# Running platform local:build in Ubuntu, receive error

Tags: linux, ubuntu, magento, platform

Running platform local:build in Ubuntu, receive error below.

I've installed Ubuntu on Windows 10 Pro 64-bit via the Linux Sub-system for Windows. Then, I installed LAMP, Composer, and the Platform.sh CLI.

Now, I've performed a get on my project to check it out locally, and am performing a build on it locally. But this is what happens:

```
$ platform local:build
Building application m2 (runtime type: php:7.0)
Found a composer.json file; installing dependencies
  Loading composer repositories with package information
  Installing dependencies (including require-dev) from lock file
  Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

Problem 1
  - magento/framework 101.0.1 requires ext-gd * -> the requested PHP extension gd is missing from your system.
  - magento/framework 101.0.1 requires ext-gd * -> the requested PHP extension gd is missing from your system.
  - Installation request for magento/framework 101.0.1 -> satisfiable by magento/framework[101.0.1].

To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in your .ini files:
  -
  - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/10-opcache.ini
  - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/10-pdo.ini
  - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/15-xml.ini
  - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-calendar.ini
  - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-ctype.ini
  - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-curl.ini
  - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-dom.ini
  - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-exif.ini
  - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-fileinfo.ini
  - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-ftp.ini
  - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-gettext.ini
  - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-iconv.ini
  - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-json.ini
  - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-phar.ini
  - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-posix.ini
  - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-readline.ini
  - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-shmop.ini
  - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-simplexml.ini
  - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-sockets.ini
  - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-sysvmsg.ini
  - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-sysvsem.ini
  - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-sysvshm.ini
  - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-tokenizer.ini
  - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-wddx.ini
  - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-xmlreader.ini
  - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-xmlwriter.ini
  - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-xsl.ini
You can also run `php --ini` inside terminal to see which files are used by PHP in CLI mode.


  [ProcessFailedException]
  The command failed with the exit code: 2

  Full command: '/usr/local/bin/composer' 'install' '--no-progress' '--prefer-dist' '--optimize-autoloader' '--no-interaction' '--no-ansi'
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the PHP-GD library was not installed or enabled on your local Ubuntu. Try installing it by:

```
sudo apt-get install php7.0-gd
```